# Conditional Distribution - X|N Binomial where N is Binomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, summation, conditional-probability

I would like to prove the following identity as a lemma to solve the following question on Conditional Distributions:

**Qn:** Let X have a binomial distribution with parameters p and N, where N has a binomial distribution with parameters q and M. What is the marginal distribution of X?

**To prove:**

$$ {\sum_{n=k}^M \frac{(M - k)!}{(n-k)!(M-n)!}(1 - p)^{n - k}(\frac{q}{1-q})^{n-k}= \left(1+\frac{q(1-p)}{1-q}\right)^{M-k}} $$

Would appreciate if anyone could advise on how to show this identity - have tried considering Binomial Expansion/GP but I can't land on the solution.

**My Solution:**

Since
$$
f_{X|N}(k|n) = \frac{f_{X,N}(k,n)}{f_N(n)}
$$
where we have the conditional probability
$$
f_{X|N}(k|n) = P(X=k|N=n) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
k
\end{array}\right) p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}, \quad k \leq n
$$
and the marginal distribution
$$
f_N(n) = P(N=n) =\left(\begin{array}{c}
M \\
n
\end{array}\right) q^{n}(1-q)^{M-n}, \quad n \leq M .
$$

Then, the joint pmf is given by

$$
P(X=k,N=n) = {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} {M \choose n} q^n(1-q)^{M-n}.
$$

Computing the marginal pmf, then

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\operatorname{Pr}\{X=k\}=\sum_{n=0}^{M} \left\{ \frac{n !}{k !(n-k) !} p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k} \frac{M !}{n !(M-n) !} q^{n}(1-q)^{M-n} \right\} \\
&=\frac{M !}{k ! (M-k)!} p^{k}(1-q)^{M}\left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)^{k} \sum_{n=k}^{M} \frac{(M-k)!}{(n-k) !(M-n) !}(1-p)^{n-k} \\
&\times\left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)^{n-k} \\
&=\frac{M !}{k !(M-k) !}(p q)^{k}(1-q)^{M-k}\left[1+\frac{q(1-p)}{1-q}\right]^{M-k} \\
&=\frac{M !}{k !(M-k) !}(p q)^{k}(1-p q)^{M-k}, \quad k=0,1, \ldots, M
\end{aligned}
$$

i.e. X ~ Bin($M, pq$).

The sum I wanted to show is between the 2nd and 3rd step.

I would admit that I attempted the book-keeping on the sum with the end in mind that I wanted to get X as a Binomial with probability $pq$, so this may not be the best solution. Would greatly appreciate if you have any alternative solutions/ideas in mind! Thanks again!

Comment: Where did the term $r$ come from?

Comment: ... Considering that you had a goal in mind, you should have just distributed out the first parts of the expression and attempted to close the remainder into the rest.  You were just making things difficult for yourself by introducing that quotient.  Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ represents a count for successes among $N$ independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate $p$, where $N$ represents a count for successes among $M$ independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate $q$.

Therefore $X$ represents a count for successes among $M$ independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate $pq$, because, to be counted among the $X$ successes, a trial must succeed at both filters.

Thus you need to demonstrate that: $\mathsf P(X=x)=\dbinom{M}{x}(pq)^x(1-pq)^{M-x}$

To begin:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X=x)&=\sum_{n=x}^M\mathsf P(N=n)\mathsf P(X=x\mid N=n)\\[1ex] & =\sum_{n=x}^M\dbinom{M}{n} q^n(1-q)^{M-n}\dbinom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}\\[1ex] &=\binom{M}{x}(pq)^x\sum_{n=x}^M\binom{M-x}{n-x}((1-p)q)^{n-x}(1-q)^{M-n}\\[1ex] &~~\vdots\\[1ex] &~~\vdots\\[1ex] &=\binom{M}{x}(pq)^x[1-pq]^{M-x}\end{align}$$

> have tried considering Binomial Expansion

That's the way to go.  Try it again.

Hint: $1-pq = (1-q)+(q-pq)$

Comment: $\small\begin{align}\dbinom Mn\dbinom nx &= \dfrac{M!}{n!~(M-n)!}\dfrac{n!}{x!~(n-x)!} \\[1ex]&=\dfrac{M!}{x!~(M-x)!}\dfrac{(M-x)!}{(n-x)!~(M-n)!}\\[1ex]&=\dbinom Mx\dbinom{M-x}{n-x}\end{align}$

Comment: Hi Graham, many thanks for your inputs, I had the same idea in mind - I updated my post above with my solution. I initially got the sum using Wolfram as I was stuck at it for a bit.

Comment: $$\small\begin{align}(A+B)^{M-k}&=\sum_{j=0}^{M-k} \binom{M-k}{j} A^j B^{(M-k)-j}\\&=\sum_{n=k}^M\dbinom{M-k}{n-k}A^{n-k}B^{(M-n)}\end{align}$$